# Using CSS Variables on Stripe Elements

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, stripe-payments

I am using `Stripe Elements` for a credit card checkout. The issue is, that I am not able (or I simply don't know how) to use my own `CSS variables` on this `Stripe Element`.
I need to use `CSS variables` for the sake of changing colors when the user changes the theme. Here is my current implementation:

**Variable definitions** (I'm using SASS)

```
.theme1
    --color-1: red
    --color-2: pink
    // ...
.theme2
    --color-1: blue
    --color-2: lilec
    // ...
.theme3
    --color-1: orange
    --color-2: yellow
    // ...
// ...
```

The `CSS variables` are defined under the scope of a class, that is put to the `body` depending which theme is currently selected.

**HTML** (I am using Angular 6)

```
<div #stripe></div>
```

**Typescript**

```
    @ViewChild('stripe') el: ElementRef;
    card: any;
    cardHandler = this.onChange.bind(this);
    async onSubmit() { /* ... */ }

    setupStripe(): void {
        this.card = stripeElements.create('card', {
            iconStyle: 'solid',
            style: {
                base: {
                    iconColor: 'var(--some-var)',
                    // using css variables here does not work
                    // ...
                },
            }
        });
        this.card.mount(this.el.nativeElement);
        this.card.addEventListener('change', this.cardHandler);
    }
    destroyStripe(): void {
        this.card.removeEventListener('change', this.cardHandler);
        this.card.destroy();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.setupStripe();
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.destroyStripe();
    }

    onChange({ error }) { /* ... */ }
```

**Styles** (I am using SASS)

```
.StripeElement
    background-color: var(--dy-bg-1)
    // I don't have access to font colors etc here
    color: var(--dy-txt-1) !important
    // !important also does not work
```

P.S.: It's important for me, that the variables will change at runtime (which is the reason I'm using CSS variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Stripe documentation says

> Elements creates UI components for you that are *hosted by Stripe*

i.e. their input fields are in a different document, so don't have access to your custom CSS variables.

A 'good enough' solution might be to read the CSS Custom Property values in your setupStripe method, and pass the values over as plain strings:

```
// Note: document.body is just an example:
const styles = getComputedStyle(document.body);
this.card = stripeElements.create("card", {
  iconStyle: "solid",
  style: {
    base: {
      iconColor: styles.getPropertyValue("--some-var")
      // ...etc
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is perfect for using the variables once! Unfortunately, the styles won't recompute after changing the body's styles. Is it possible to alter the `cards` styles after `creating`?

Comment: Stripe documentation says "The styles of an Element can be dynamically changed using update(). This method can be used to simulate CSS media queries that automatically adjust the size of Elements when viewed on different devices.".  See https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#other-methods

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this! I'll try it out and you get a green arrow if it worked :)